Dash Web App: Adding block of code messes up the entire app
I am making a web app using python and dash. Everything seems to go well except when I add the last callback function add_new_parcel_submit to update my database. When I add this, the login page is not showing and the navbar is not responding to change links.
Here is my index.py:
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        # Location Variable -- contains details about the url
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=True),
        
        # LOGIN DATA
        # 1) logout indicator, storage_type='session' means that data will be retained
        #  until browser/tab is closed (vs clearing data upon refresh)
        dcc.Store(id='sessionlogout', data=True, storage_type='session'),
        
        # 2) current_user_id -- stores user_id
        dcc.Store(id='currentuserid', data=-1, storage_type='session'),
        
        # 3) currentrole -- stores the role
        # we will not use them but if you have roles, you can use it
        dcc.Store(id='currentrole', data=-1, storage_type='session'),

        # Adding the navbar
        html.Div(
            cm.navbar,
            id='navbar_div'
        ),

        # Page Content -- Div that contains page layout
        html.Div(id='page-content', style=CONTENT_STYLE),

    ]
)


@app.callback(
    [
        Output('page-content', 'children'),
        Output('sessionlogout', 'data'),
        Output('navbar_div', 'className'),
    ],
    [
        # If the path (i.e. part after the website name; 
        # in url = youtube.com/watch, path = '/watch') changes, 
        # the callback is triggered
        Input('url', 'pathname')
    ],
    [
        State('sessionlogout', 'data'),
        State('currentuserid', 'data'),
    ]
)


def displaypage (pathname,
                 sessionlogout, userid):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if ctx.triggered:
        eventid = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
        
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    
    if eventid == 'url':
        if userid < 0: # if logged out
            if pathname == '/':
                returnlayout = login.layout
            elif pathname == '/signup':
                returnlayout = signup.layout
            else:
                returnlayout = '404: request not found'
            
        else:    
            if pathname == '/logout':
                returnlayout = login.layout
                sessionlogout = True
                
            elif pathname == '/' or pathname == '/home':
                # From the imported module 'home', we get the layout variable
                returnlayout = home.layout

            elif pathname == '/parcel_management':
                returnlayout = parcel_management.layout

            elif pathname == '/parcel_management/add_new_group':
                returnlayout = add_new_parcel_group.layout
            elif pathname == '/parcel_management/add_new_parcel':
                returnlayout = add_new_parcel.layout
            elif pathname == '/parcel_management/update_parcel_group':
                returnlayout = update_parcel_group.layout
            elif pathname == '/parcel_management/update_parcel_status':
                returnlayout = update_parcel_status.layout

            elif pathname == '/dashboard':
                returnlayout = dashboard.layout

            elif pathname == '/parcel_forecast':
                returnlayout = parcel_forecast.layout

            else:
                returnlayout = '404: request not found'
                
        # decide sessionlogout value
        logout_conditions = [
            pathname in ['/', '/logout'],
            userid == -1,
            not userid
        ]
        sessionlogout = any(logout_conditions)
        
        # hide navbar if logged-out; else, set class/style to default
        navbar_classname = 'd-none' if sessionlogout else ''
        
        return [returnlayout, sessionlogout, navbar_classname]
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate


if __name__ == '__main__':
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8050/', new=0, autoraise=True)
    app.run_server(debug=False)



here is my login.py
from app import app
from apps import dbconnect as db

layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2('Please Login'),
        html.Hr(),
        dbc.Alert('Username or password is incorrect.', color="danger", id='login_alert',
                  is_open=False),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Label("Username", width=2),
                dbc.Col(
                    dbc.Input(
                        type="text", id="login_username", placeholder="Enter username"
                    ),
                    width=6,
                ),
            ],
            className="mb-3",
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Label("Password", width=2),
                dbc.Col(
                    dbc.Input(
                        type="password", id="login_password", placeholder="Enter password"
                    ),
                    width=6,
                ),
            ],
            className="mb-3",
        ),
        dbc.Button('Login', color="secondary", id='login_loginbtn'),
        html.Hr(),
        html.A('Signup Now!', href='/signup'),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    [
        Output('login_alert', 'is_open'),
        Output('currentuserid', 'data'),
    ],
    [
        Input('login_loginbtn', 'n_clicks'), # begin login query via button click
        Input('sessionlogout', 'modified_timestamp'), # reset session userid to -1 if logged out
    ],
    [
        State('login_username', 'value'),
        State('login_password', 'value'),   
        State('sessionlogout', 'data'),
        State('currentuserid', 'data'), 
        State('url', 'pathname'), 
    ]
)
def loginprocess(loginbtn, sessionlogout_time,
                 
                 username, password,
                 sessionlogout, currentuserid,
                 pathname):
    
    ctx = callback_context
    
    if ctx.triggered:
        openalert = False
        eventid = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    
    if eventid == 'login_loginbtn': # trigger for login process
    
        if loginbtn and username and password:
            sql = """SELECT user_id
            FROM users
            WHERE 
                user_name = %s AND
                user_password = %s AND
                NOT user_delete_ind"""
            
            # we match the encrypted input to the encrypted password in the db
            encrypt_string = lambda string: hashlib.sha256(string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() 
            
            values = [username, encrypt_string(password)]
            cols = ['userid']
            df = db.querydatafromdatabase(sql, values, cols)
            
            if df.shape[0]: # if query returns rows
                currentuserid = df['userid'][0]
            else:
                currentuserid = -1
                openalert = True
                
    elif eventid == 'sessionlogout' and pathname == '/logout': # reset the userid if logged out
        currentuserid = -1
        
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    return [openalert, currentuserid]


@app.callback(
    [
        Output('url', 'pathname'),
    ],
    [
        Input('currentuserid', 'modified_timestamp'),
    ],
    [
        State('currentuserid', 'data'), 
    ]
)
def routelogin(logintime, userid):
    ctx = callback_context
    if ctx.triggered:
        if userid > 0:
            url = '/home'
        else:
            url = '/'
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
    return [url]

here is my update_parcel_status.py
dash.register_page(__name__, path='/')


layout = dbc.Container([
    html.H1("Update Parcel Status"),
    dbc.Form([
        dbc.CardGroup([  # Use CardGroup instead of FormGroup
            dbc.Label("Parcel ID*"),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='parcel-id',
                placeholder="Select Status",
                style={'width': '100%'} 
            ),
        ]),
        dbc.CardGroup([  # Use CardGroup instead of FormGroup
            dbc.Label("Status*"),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='status-id',
                placeholder="Select Status",
                style={'width': '100%'} 
            ),
        ]),
        dbc.CardGroup([  # Use CardGroup instead of FormGroup
            dbc.Label("Location"),
            dbc.Input(type="text", id="location"),
        ]),
        html.Br(),
        dbc.Button("Update Status", id="update-button", color="primary"),
        html.Div(id='output-container-button'),  # Placeholder for callback output
    ]),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=60000,  # in milliseconds
        n_intervals=0
    )
], fluid=True)



@app.callback(
    Output('status-id', 'options'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')]
)
def update_status_options(n):
    print("Callback1")  # Debug statement to check if callback is triggered
    try:
        # Fetch data from the parcelstatus_mapping table
        query = """
            SELECT status_id, status_desc
            FROM parcelstatus_mapping;
        """
        df = db.querydatafromdatabase(query, values=[], dfcolumns=['status_id', 'status_desc'])
        # print (df)
        # Convert DataFrame to a list of dictionaries suitable for dropdown options
        options = [{'label': desc, 'value': str(status_id)} for status_id, desc in zip(df['status_id'], df['status_desc'])]


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data for status options: {e}")
        options = []

    return options



@app.callback(
    Output('parcel-id', 'options'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')]
)
def update_parcel_options(n):

    print("Callback2")  # Debug statement to check if callback is triggered
    try:
        # Fetch data from the parcel_status table

        # print('a')

        query = """
            SELECT parcel_id
            FROM parcel_status;
        """

        
        df = db.querydatafromdatabase(query, values=[], dfcolumns=['parcel_id'])

        # Convert DataFrame to a list of dictionaries suitable for dropdown options
        options = [{'label': str(parcel_id), 'value': str(parcel_id)} for parcel_id in df['parcel_id']]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data for parcel options: {e}")
        options = []

    return options


@app.callback(
    Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    [Input('update-button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('url', 'pathname')],
    [State('parcel-id', 'value'),
     State('location', 'value')]

)
def add_new_parcel_submit(n_clicks, parcel_id, location, pathname):
    if pathname != '/parcel_management/update_parcel_status':
        raise PreventUpdate  # Callback only runs when URL matches '/parcel_management/update_parcel_status'

    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate
    # return [html.Div([f"Parcel ID: {parcel_id}, Location: {location}"])]
    print("Callback triggered with n_clicks:", n_clicks)  # Debug statement to check if callback is triggered
    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate

    alert_open = True
    alert_color = 'danger'
    alert_text = 'Failed to add new parcel.'
    modal_open = False

    if not all([parcel_id,  location]):
        alert_text = 'Check your inputs. Please fill in all the required fields.'
        print("Not all fields filled:", parcel_id,  location)  # Debug statement for incomplete fields
    else:
        try:
            # Constructing the SQL query
            sql = '''
                INSERT INTO parcel_status (parcel_id,  update_timestamp, location)
            '''
            # Adding the values to the values list
            values = [parcel_id, 1, datetime.now(), location]
            print("SQL values:", values)  # Debug statement for SQL values

            sql += ') VALUES (' + ', '.join(['%s'] * len(values)) + ')'
            print("SQL query:", sql)  # Debug statement for constructed SQL query
            
            # db.modifydatabase(sql, values)
            print("Database modification successful")  # Debug statement for successful database modification

            alert_open = True
            alert_color = 'success'
            alert_text = 'New parcel added successfully.'
            modal_open = True
        except Exception as e:
            alert_text = f'Failed to add new parcel: {str(e)}'
            print("Exception occurred:", e)  # Debug statement for exception

    return [html.Div(alert_text, className=f'alert alert-{alert_color}', role='alert'), modal_open]

I tried to check the ids and all seems to be correct. i tried to put the preventupdate for the
add_new_parcel_submit to only be called when in that url, but adding that callback still breaks the code even if outside that url. Can you help pls? I am stucked for days here huhu

Use app.run_server(debug=True) to see if there is any error/warning, you can also check for errors directly in the browser console.
